# Is it possible to write a Distributive Instance for ScalaCheck's Gen type?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monad-transformers, scala-cats, scalacheck

I'm trying to write a Monad Transformer instance for ScalaCheck's `Gen` Type.

That is: a type such as the following, which could be used as a Monad, for provided that the underlying functor `F` is a Monad.

```scala
case class GeneratorT[F[_], A](generator: Gen[F[A]])

object GeneratorT {
  implicit def monadForGeneratorT[F[_]: Monad]: Monad[GeneratorT[F, *]] = new Monad[GeneratorT[F, *]] {
        ...
    }
}
```

While writing this, I realized that it would be useful if I was able to write a `Distributive` instance for `Gen`, because then I'd be able to write `flatMap` for `GeneratorT` in the following (somewhat convoluted) way:

```scala
    override def flatMap[A, B](ga: GeneratorT[F, A])(fun: A => GeneratorT[F, B]): GeneratorT[F, B] = {
      GeneratorT[F, B](ga.generator.flatMap(fa => fa.map(a => fun(a).generator).distribute(identity).map(_.flatten)))
    }
```

Instinctively, I feel like I should be able to write a `Distributive` instance for `Gen` because `Gen` is *more or less* just a function from some configuration, and a seed, onto a value, and functions are distributive.

With that said, I've failed to find an example of anyone doing this, and I'm struggling to write it, because ScalaCheck doesn't expose the internals of `Gen`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand why this isn't quite possible; it's because `Gen` supports filtering, and as such, it's possible to end out with a `Gen` that has no valid values.

I was thinking of `Gen` as a function `(Properties, Seed) => A`, but actually, this should be more like `(Properties, Seed) => Option[A]`.

The first type distributes, the second doesn't.

For example an `IO[Gen[A]]` can't be converted to a `Gen[IO[A]]` if the `Gen` might fail, because there's no way to know about the failure without evaluating the `IO`.

If you pretend that any Generator will produce a value if evaluated enough times, and you're willing to encounter exceptions when this isn't the case, it's possible to implement `Distributive` like so:

```scala
  implicit val distributiveForGen: Distributive[Gen] = new Distributive[Gen] {
    override def distribute[G[_]: Functor, A, B](ga: G[A])(f: A => Gen[B]): Gen[G[B]] =
      Gen.parameterized(params => ga.map(a => f(a).pureApply(params, params.initialSeed.getOrElse(Seed(0)))))

    override def map[A, B](fa: Gen[A])(f: A => B): Gen[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to hold off on acceping this anwser, because I'm still not 100% sure about it, and want to give it a chance to be corrected